# g++ can't find ncurses.h despite it being installed

Tags: c++, gcc, linker-errors, ncurses

I'm trying to experiment around in ncurses for the first time, but I'm having problems compiling my source code. As far as I can tell, ncurses is installed and in the proper directories.

My makefile is super simple:

```
.cpp :
    g++ -Wall -g -o $* $*.cpp -std=c++11 -lncurses
```

and here's my output when I try to `locate ncurses.h`

```
$ locate ncurses.h
/usr/include/ncursesw/ncurses.h
```

and when I check to see if it's installed

```
$ dpkg -l | grep ncurses
ii  libncurses5:amd64                                     5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1                               amd64        shared libraries for terminal handling
ii  libncursesw5:amd64                                    5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1                               amd64        shared libraries for terminal handling (wide character support)
ii  libncursesw5-dev:amd64                                5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1                               amd64        developer's libraries for ncursesw
ii  mtr-tiny                                              0.85-2                                              amd64        Full screen ncurses traceroute tool
ii  ncurses-base                                          5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1                               all          basic terminal type definitions
ii  ncurses-bin                                           5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1                               amd64        terminal-related programs and man pages
ii  ncurses-term                                          5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1                               all          additional terminal type definitions
```

But g++ tells me this when I try to make

```
bankacct.cpp:18:29: fatal error: ncurses.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Unfortunately, I've not got root access and I need to be able to compile on this machine. What are my options?

---

I've tried including `<ncursesw/ncurses.h>` based on suggestions from other users, but now g++ is giving me this error:

```
$ make bankacct
g++ -Wall -g -o bankacct bankacct.cpp -std=c++11 -lncurses
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses
```

and if I try removing `-lncurses` it gives me this:

```
$ make bankacct
g++ -Wall -g -o bankacct bankacct.cpp -std=c++11
/tmp/cc8rPQfK.o: In function `main':
bankacct.cpp:23: undefined reference to `initscr'
```

---

Now I've tried linking the libraries. Here's what I did:

```
$ locate libncurse
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5.9
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5.9
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses++w.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so
/usr/share/doc/libncurses5
/usr/share/doc/libncursesw5
/usr/share/doc/libncursesw5-dev
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5:amd64.symbols
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw5-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw5-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw5-dev:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw5:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw5:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw5:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw5:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw5:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw5:amd64.symbols
```

So then I tried two variations of my makefile:

```
g++ -Wall -g -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -o $* $*.cpp -std=c++11 -lncurses
```

and

```
g++ -Wall -g -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -o $* $*.cpp -std=c++11 -lncurses
```

which still gave me the errors `undefined reference to 'initscr'` (without `-lncurses`) or `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses` (with it)

Comment: Are you including the header like `#include <ncursesw/ncurses.h>` in your source code?

Comment: I have tried both `#include <ncurses.h>` and `#include <ncurses/ncurses.h>` and g++ tells me `ncurses.h: No such file or directory`. My entire program as of now is essentially just `#include <ncurses.h>`

Comment: what is that w doing next to `/usr/include/ncursesw/` ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know. It's not my machine.

Comment: I tried `#include <ncursesw/ncurses.h>` and now g++ is telling me `g++ -Wall -g -o bankacct bankacct.cpp -std=c++11 -lncurses
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses`

Comment: one step ahead. It's compiling. Time to link. now `locate libncurse`, then add `-L/path/to/thatdirectory` to your compilation flags

Comment: Just discovered that `ncursesw` exists http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html

Comment: Please refer to my latest edit.

Comment: @OttovonBisquick You still need the `-lncurses`, `-L` just specifies where to search it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't show that in above - I'll edit it. Unfortunately it still gives me `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses` in either directory.

Comment: forgot that `w` ?

Comment: Flint, please submit this as the answer. This was what I was doing wrong this entire time - I need to use the `-lncursesw` flag rather than the `lncurses` flag. Thanks so much!

Comment: The `-l...` flag has nothing to do with how the compiler finds a `.h` file. You should be able to use `#include <ncurses.h>`. On my system, `/usr/include/ncurses.h` exists (it's a symlink to `curses.h`, and it's provided by the `libncurses5-dev:amd64` package). I can compile and link with `g++ c.cpp -o c -lncurses`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
-lncurses
```

tells the linker to look for a library called "ncurses.". You clearly indicate that's not what your library is called:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.a
```

You need

```
-lncursesw
```

You don't need to modify the source code to specify `<ncursesw/ncurses.h>` you can simply add

```
-I/usr/include/ncursesw
```