# How to compile "Hello World" using ncurses in C on Kali

Tags: c, gcc, ncurses

I have successfully installed ncurses in Kali (at least the included examples in the ncurses-6.1/test folder work), but I can't compile anything myself.

My code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(void)
{
    initscr();
    printw("Hello World!!");
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Failed Compilation:

```
gcc game.c -lncurses

fatal error: ncurses.h: No such file or directory
```

I have exhaustively studied this similar question, among others:

[g++ can't find ncurses.h despite it being installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39522115/g-cant-find-ncurses-h-despite-it-being-installed)

Unfortunately, after trying various permutations of including curses.h vs. ncurses.h, compiling with -lncurses or -lncursesw, etc., I have to ask the community for help!

Comment: How did you install ncurses?

Comment: He probably did not install the development package (which would provide `ncurses.h`).

Comment: For installation, I used: wget ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses/ncurses-6.1.tar.gz    tar xzf ncurses-6.1.tar.gz    cd ncurses-6.1/    make install    ls -la /opt/ncurses      This was all as per a tutorial I found.

Comment: Initially I tried installing dev packages apt-get install libncurses5-dev and libncursesw5-dev. Since apt-get didn't know where to find them, I used wget to download ncurses-6.1 instead.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Thanks so much for your work in creating ncurses! I dabbled with it a few years ago, though my recent attempts to install it have struck out.

Comment: to solve this fundamental issue : "E: Unable to locate package libncurses-dev." you need to update settings in package manager ... open up Dash and search for software then pick  Software & Updates -> now checkmark on where it says Downloadable from the Internet : the ones saying (main) (universe) (restricted) (multiverse) ... then hit tab Other Software and assure you have checkmark on for : Canonical Partners and source code ... then issue ... sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade ... now issue ... sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev

Comment: @Scott The "Software" update program built-in to Kali is really minimal. I just don't see the options you described.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you installed manually. If this is the case then you need to `#include "/path/to/ncurses.h"` wherever you have it installed.

If you used aptitude (which afaik is the default Kali package manager) you will likely need to install the development package via `apt-get install libncurses-dev`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: (1) I tried "locate ncurses.h" then using the path it gave, I changed my include to #include "/opt/ncurses/include/ncurses/ncurses.h" which changed the compiler error to "fatal error: ncurses/ncurses_dll.h: No such file or directory."

Comment: (2) When I ran "apt-get install libncurses-dev" it said "E: Unable to locate package libncurses-dev." According to https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/ncurses, it looks like Kali *should* have any ncurses package one would need.

Comment: (1) Try editing your makefile (or add to `gcc` directly) `-I/opt/ncurses/include/ncurses` you will also need to add `-L/path/to/ncurses.so` wherever that's installed. After adding the `-I` flag you can change your include back to `#include <ncurses.h>`.

Comment: (2) If `apt-get install ncurses` is installing the header, look for it around `/usr/include/ncurses`. If you can find it in that directory the fix may be as simple as `#include <ncurses/ncurses.h>` since by default `gcc` should look for includes in `/usr/include`. If it's not there, then stick with the manual install you've got going, but personally I think you'd do better to use the package manager.

Comment: I changed the include back to plain old <ncurses.h> and ran gcc like this: gcc game.c -I/opt/ncurses/include/ncurses -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5 -lncurses, but got "fatal error: ncurses/ncurses_dll.h: No such file or directory." I'd *much* prefer using the package manager, but "apt-get install ncurses" is unable to locate the package.

Comment: try "apt-cache search ncurses" to find the proper name of the ncurses dev package to install.

Comment: Maybe try `-I/opt/ncurses/include` instead, that way it's searching through the `ncurses` directory there to find `ncurses_dll.h`. This will require you to change back to `#include <ncurses/ncurses.h>`. That sucks that you're unable to install via package manager; normally I'd say fix that first, but you seem like you're on a deadline.

Comment: @OregonJim apt-cache search ncurses found several (libncurses5, ncurses-term, libtinfo-dev, etc), but nothing with both ncurses and dev in the name.

Comment: @NewtHoenikker When I changed the include back to `#include <ncurses/ncurses.h>` and used the `-I/opt/ncurses/include` option, it gave a different error: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`    I'm wondering if I need to read a book on compiling code with shared libraries or something, since I'm blindly following suggestions without understanding how the suggestions work under the hood. P.S. This is a hobby project, wanting to write a game with a simple "GUI" in ncurses, so no deadline.

Comment: The `-I` flag tells `gcc` where to look for header files to be included. The `-L` flag tells it where to look for binaries to be linked. If `ld` isn't finding your library then you've likely pointed to an incorrect directory using `-L`. I would strongly recommend getting comfortable with C and your build tools before trying a project like this, but if this is how you choose to learn so be it.

Answer (score 1):

In light of @Thomas Dickey's comment, I went to invisible-island.net/ncurses and downloaded a clean copy from the "Development ncurses source (gzip's tar via http)" link and reinstalled everything with `./configure` `make install` `make` and then everything just magically worked.

No extra command line arguments were needed. It was simply `gcc game.c -lncurses` using a source file with `#include <ncurses.h>`. That said, I don't know why it didn't work before with other peoples' suggestions. The previous ncurses I'd downloaded did have the header file.

Answer (score 0):

You should compile your program using the -I flag or -iquote with the path of the directory containing your ncurses.h file

For me: 
`gcc game.c -lncurses -iquote/usr/include/`

Or you can change your include to `#include </usr/include/ncurses.h>`

Comment: Running `locate ncurses.h` gave me `/opt/ncurses/include/ncurses/ncurses.h`, so then I tried to compile like this: `gcc game.c -lncurses -iquote/opt/ncurses/include/ncurses/` but it still says `fatal error: ncurses.h: No such file or directory.` This is really weird since `locate` was able to find the header in that location.

Comment: Have you tried To move your ncurses.h in the /usr/include directory ?

Comment: I just copied ncurses.h into /usr/include, which changed the compiler error into not finding the .dll. We might be getting closer. Maybe if I just keep moving files into  /usr/include it'll eventually work...

Comment: After playing whack-a-mole moving each file over that the compiler couldn't find (ncurses_dll.h, unctrl.h, llib-lncurses), this approach just isn't working.

Comment: Have you tried to install the ncurses using the github and not apt-get ?

Comment: I haven't, but something else worked. I'll write it up below.

Answer (score 0):

The key evidence is when you said

> When I ran "apt-get install libncurses-dev" it said "E: Unable to locate package libncurses-dev."

which means your machine needs to get setup to access a wider spread of packages, once it does it will find that package.  issue this

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

we just need to better populate that file ... since Kali is based on debian version testing, following link can synthesize the needed proper content of /etc/apt/sources.list

https://debgen.simplylinux.ch/

assuming (I do not have Kali box handy) its using debian testing, just backup sources.list, empty it and paste below into your /etc/apt/sources.list ( synthesized from https://debgen.simplylinux.ch/ )

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                   OFFICIAL DEBIAN REPOS                    
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

###### Debian Main Repos
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security testing/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security testing/updates main
```

in above take notice of the word testing in each line, a different debian release will replace that word with say jessie or stretch ...   then issue

```
sudo  apt install curl wget apt-transport-https dirmngr 

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

finally you are ready to install

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev
```

Any repos you may have had in original /etc/apt/sources.list can be put back into that file

**PS** kind folks have also provided a similar list synthesizer for ubuntu             https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/